# python - keep duplicates if two columns equal

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like below:

```
col1.  col2.  col3. 
a      b       c
a      d       x
b      c       e
s      f       e
f      f       e
```

I need to drop duplicates in `col3` if `col1` differs from `col2`. The result looks like:

```
col1.  col2.  col3. 
a      b       c
a      d       x
f      f       e
```

Is there a way to nest this condition in `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col3'])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we can do `argsort`

```
df = df.iloc[df.eval('col1==col2').argsort()].drop_duplicates('col3',keep='last')
  col1 col2 col3
0    a    b    c
1    a    d    x
4    f    f    e
```

Comment: Great answer.  The data being presorted may make it a little non-obvious what's really happening.